# Las rutas de linkeo cambian cuando subo mi web a github

Tags: github-pages

Cuando subo mi carpeta raiz al repositorio de github y abro el github pages no me cargan los estilos, ni las imagenes, nada... Parece que todos las rutas cambias.
Alguna manera de solucionarlo sin tener que cambiar ruta por ruta?

https://github.com/criscarabajal/entregafinal

https://criscarabajal.github.io/entregafinal/

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro, has intentado borrar el cache del navegador, intenta borrando el cache del navegador con ctrl + shift + R;

Ok hice un fork a tu repositorio, modifique el head, al parecer los link del bootstrap estan mal, voy hacer un pull request a tu repositorio para que veas los cambios que eh hecho.

Comment: Hice eso y me trajo algunos estilos. Pero sigue sin traerme imagenes, fuentes, el bootstrap y demas. Y desde local lo veo perfectamente.

Comment: Ok hice un fork a tu repositorio, modifique el head, al parecer los link del bootstrap estan mal, voy hacer un pull request a tu repositorio para que veas los cambios que eh hecho.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho! Me esta trayendo el bootstrap ahora. Lo que no entiendo es por que me cambia los links cuando subo al repositorio. Las imagenes y demas no me las trae.

Comment: No te trae las imagenes? que raro cambia el link de las imagenes en ves de poner /assets/img.png pon assets/img.png elimina el / en la ruta

Comment: Muchas gracias! Con eso pude traer las imagen. Lamentablemente me pasa en todas las paginas asi que a mano estoy cambiando las rutas. Gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: A la orden amigo.